# Bind variable error in SQL trigger

Tags: sql, plsql

Here is my trigger.Following error.
 45  /
SP2-0552: Bind variable "OLD" not declared.
I am  unable to find the error .I have tried several times but failed.I have declared every variable but the error is showing.Someone please help me .

```
drop trigger DELETE_Single_food
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DELETE_Single_food
BEFORE DELETE ON SingleFoodOrder
FOR EACH ROW


declare

f_price number;
old_bill   number;
f_quantity     number;
p_bill  number;
foodID number;
orderID number;
order_date Date;
s_date Date;
f_date Date;
f_dis  number;
a number;
b number;
c number; 
BEGIN  
    IF :old.H_delivery_ID is not NULL then
        foodID := :old.Fooditem_ID;
        orderID := :old.H_delivery_ID;
        f_quantity := :old.Quantity;
        select bill into old_bill from HomeDelivery where H_delivery_ID =orderID ;
        select price into f_price from Food_Item where Fooditem_ID = foodID;
        select discount_percentage into f_dis from Food_Item where Fooditem_ID = foodID;
        select start_date into s_date from Food_Item where Fooditem_ID = foodID;
        select deadline into f_date from Food_Item where Fooditem_ID = foodID;
        select H_delivery_request into order_date from HomeDelivery where H_delivery_ID =orderID;
        if f_dis is not NULL then

            if (order_date >= s_date  and order_date<=f_date) then
                 a := f_dis/100;
                 b := f_price*a ;
                 c := f_price-b;

                 p_bill := old_bill-( c*f_quantity); 
                 update HomeDelivery set bill = p_bill where H_delivery_ID = orderID;                 
            else
                 p_bill := old_bill-(f_price*f_quantity);
                 update HomeDelivery set bill = p_bill where H_delivery_ID = orderID;
            end if;
        else  
            p_bill := old_bill-(f_price*f_quantity);
            update HomeDelivery set bill = p_bill where H_delivery_ID = orderID;  
        end if;      
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in your variables declarations. I think you're not closing your main IF statement:

```
IF :old.H_delivery_ID is not NULL then
```

I don't see the END IF for that one. Add END IF; before the END;
If this does not work, you will need to do some debugging. Try just to leave only that statement in the begin block.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DELETE_Single_food
BEFORE DELETE ON SingleFoodOrder
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN  
    IF :old.H_delivery_ID is not NULL then
        null;
    END IF;
END;
/
```

See if that compiles. Then add the rest of the code to see where it breaks.
Hope this helps!